# AttributeError: 'FileInput' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code

```
import fileinput
import json

with fileinput.input(files=('bot_details.json')) as f:
    my_load = json.load(f)
    TOKEN=my_load["TOKEN"]
```

I'm getting this error,
`AttributeError: 'FileInput' object has no attribute 'read'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single file use open

```
with open('bot_details.json') as f:
    my_load = json.load(f)
    TOKEN=my_load["TOKEN"]
```

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake, check again